# How to properly use xgb.train with both subsample and watchlist parameters?

Tags: r, xgboost

I need to use the `xgb.train` function from the xgboost R package, and I was looking at the various [`parameters`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html). Among those, `subsample` sounds like it could be used in place of splitting the dataset into a train and validation set (I am not 100% sure about this though, please if anybody can confirm I would be grateful).

> Subsample ratio of the training instances. Setting it to 0.5 means
> that XGBoost would randomly sample half of the training data prior to
> growing trees. and this will prevent overfitting. Subsampling will
> occur once in every boosting iteration.

Now, I like that `xgb.train` has

> the capacity to follow the progress of the learning after each round ([source](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/R-package/xgboostPresentation.html#measure-learning-progress-with-xgb-train))

using the `watchlist` parameter. However, how am I suppose to follow the progress of the learning if I don't explicitly pass the validation set to the `wathclist`? Will just passing the data that I use as my `data` argument to the `xgb.train` function suffice if I am also defining `subsample` as `0.7`?

To clarify, here is a code example:

```
my_mod <- xgb.train(
    params = my_params,
    data = my_data,
    eval_metric = "rmse",
    watchlist = list(train = my_data),
    early_stopping_rounds = 100,
    nrounds = 1000,
    subsample=0.7)
```

Comment: You're interested in the learning progress on the training set, not so much on an explicit validation set? The `verbose` parameter can be used for that purpose.

Comment: Ok, but I just noticed that if I remove the `watchlist` I loose the ability to use `early_stopping_rounds`. Also, unfortunately the output messages from `verbosity` are very different (and a bit "messy" to my personal taste) than those I am used with `watchlist` (they don't seem to print the RMSE improvement at all). I am interested in the progress of learning on the training set BUT taking into account the `subsample` parameter should take out a validation set at each round.